# Python Client Library for Kubernetes give an error

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am getting this error and I have search over google a lot but could not understand it correctly yet. I am not sending in any explicity Configuration object so it is all abstract what is going on here

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 238, in sanitize_for_serialization
    for attr, _ in six.iteritems(obj.openapi_types)
AttributeError: 'Configuration' object has no attribute 'openapi_types'
```

One thing that I could understand was to change the job object that is sent to the create_job method of the library  as a dictionary object. But still this error is not going away.

Can anyone please give some insight into this? Thanks

Comment: Please attach to the question your code (or a fragment) that doesn't work.

Comment: @muasif80 did you find any solution to this problem?